# CUDAMap does not work for the Sqrt function

Tags: bugs, cudalink

CUDALink is working fine on my LINUX machine. I am using *Mathematica* 11.1 and `CUDAMap` works for all of the functions that it supports:

`Cos`, `Sin`, `Tan`, `ArcCos`, `ArcSin`, `ArcTan`, `Cosh`, `Sinh`, `Exp`, `Log`, `Log10`, `Ceiling`, `Floor`, and `Abs`,

**Except `Sqrt`.** It says in the `CUDAMap` documentation that `Sqrt` should work.

In the `map.cu` file, this code is present:

```c
if (StringSameQ(op, "Cos")) {
    cos_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "Sin")) {
    sin_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "Tan")) {
    tan_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "ArcCos")) {
    acos_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "ArcSin")) {
    asin_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "ArcTan")) {
    atan_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "Cosh")) {
    cosh_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "Sinh")) {
    sinh_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "Tanh")) {
    tanh_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "Exp")) {
    exp_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "Log")) {
    log_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "Log10")) {
    log10_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
//} else if (StringSameQ(op, "Sqrt")) {
//  sqrt_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "Ceil") || StringSameQ(op, "Ceiling")) {
    ceil_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "Floor")) {
    floor_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else if (StringSameQ(op, "Abs")) {
    abs_operator<T><<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(input, output, len);
} else {
    return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
}
```

As you can see, the `Sqrt` portion of the `if` statement is commented out. When I try to change this and delete the `//`, I cannot save and rewrite the `map.cu` file in the directory `/Mathematica/SystemFiles/Links/CUDALink/CSource`. I am guessing that there is no way to do this because I do not have *write* privileges here. Is there a way I could load my own `map.cu` CUDA function with the `Sqrt` function enabled?

Also, does anyone know why the `Sqrt` section of this code is disabled to begin with?

Comment: The sqrt_operator might be considered redundant to the exp_operator

Comment: @PeterRoberge the exp_operator represents only e^

Comment: I had a look in my system (Windows version of MMA 11.0). Sqrt is also commented out. If // is deleted in the map.cu it is still not working either. In the CUDA reference of NVIDIA there is the sqrt function described. That is also not the issue. So there seems no way out yet except for writing an own code. Can you elaborate on why you need Sqrt as CUDA version?

Comment: Well, you could use the `Exp` and the `Log` Function instead, i.e. `Sqrt[x] = Exp[0.5 * Log[x]]`. But sure, `Sqrt` should work out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to duplicate this and contacted wolfram technical support after a little back and forth they finally confirmed it as a bug. They said they would notify the development team. Hopefully this will be fixed in a future release.

-- Harry Kramer